# JQuery on() usage and overwriting

Tags: javascript, jquery, memory-leaks, event-handling

I am working on a mobile app, and I am currently using the `on()` method to implement a swipe-to-delete feature (I understand that there are libraries that would allow me to do this, and am open to any thoughts you have on the merits of different options).  I have code that looks like this:

```
 var favArticles = $('#favoritesList li');
 favArticles.each(function(i, li){
     var id = $(li).attr('id');
     $(li).on("swipeLeft",function(){
         //console.log('SwipeLeft ' + id);
         var html = $(li).html();
         var button = '<div ><button onclick="favDelete(id, i)">Delete</a></div>';
         $(li).html('<div style="position:relative;">' + html + button + '</div>');
     });
 });
```

I am trying to manage a mutable list of articles that, so whenever I render the favorites list, I grab all the current articles, and bind a swipe event to them.  If swiped, a button is brought up on top of the article, and when the user hits the button a function runs that removes the swiped li from the list, and deletes it from the stored favorites.

Within favDelete, I use the index `i` to remove() the correct `li`.  This means that I need to recreate all the events with updated values of i each time an element is deleted.

So, my question: if I call `on()` again, for the same event on the same DOM element, will the old binding be overwritten?  Or do I create a memory leak by constantly adding new `on()` actions to my list elements?

UPDATE: Yes, JQuery, not Javascript.  Apologies.  And I know that my favDelete call won't work as it is shown, I omitted chopped a bunch of quotation marks out for the post to try to improve readability.

Comment: `on()` does not overwrite. It will always create a new event handler. If you want to clear certain handlers, use `off('swipeLeft')` or just `off()` for everything.

Comment: javascript has an `on()` `function`? What a world...

Comment: `onclick="favDelete(id, i)"` would not work as you think. I would create DOM elements instead of HTML strings, and I would use DOM traversal to find the right `li` element to delete. You manage this with just one event handler bound to the list.

Comment: You could you use one() if you know for sure that you will only use this event once http://api.jquery.com/one/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would just use two event handlers and event delegation: One for the swipe event and one for the click on the delete button.
I don't know if `swipeLeft` works with event delegation, but even if not, it would not change much:

```
$('#favoritesList').on('swipeLeft', 'li', function() {
    // show delete button
    // or $(this).html(...)
    $(this).append('<div class="deleteButton"><button>Delete</a></div>');
}).on('click', '.deleteButton button', function() {
    // find ancestor li element
    var $li = $(this).closest('li');
    // and pass it to favDelete
    favDelete($li);
    // if you don't remove the element in the favDelete, do it here:
    $li.remove();
});
```

Using event delegation for the delete buttons makes the most sense, since you are "constantly" adding and removing them.

**[Learn more about event delegation](http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/).**

All the styling you can do with a CSS rule for the `deleteButton` class. You'd also have to change your `favDelete` method to accept a `li` element (or rather a jQuery object with a `li` element) instead of an ID and index.

---

> if I call `on()` again, for the same event on the same DOM element, will the old binding be overwritten?

`.on()` will always **add** a new event handler. In your code, you even create a new event handler function for every list element, which is indeed a waste of memory.

In my code above, there are only *two* event handlers for all `li` and `button` elements.

Comment: Thank you for your help, this is much cleaner

Answer (score 0):

Two other ways you could do this, rather than a hard-coded index:

1. Use the ID to select the correct `LI` element (in your favDelete function)
2. Pass in a selector instead of the index (i.e. `$(this).closest('li')`)

Answer (score 0):

If You'll call 'on' again, previous bindings will still be alive - for ex. If You'll call few times (let's say 5 times) on('click', function() { console.log('fired'); }. When You'll click one time on the object it'll thorw 'fired' five times.